# d3.js ajax default headers/before send

Tags: ajax, d3.js, http-headers

I need to set headers for all d3.js xhr calls. I know you can set it for singular calls

`d3.json("/path").header('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest')`

I am looking for something like jQuery's beforeSend method

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the d3 source code (look for `function d3_xhr`), or just take my word for it (I just looked) that there's no way to specify default headers for `d3.json()`

However, nothing is preventing you from creating and using your own method for this, like

```
function myJson(args) {
  // call d3's json, passing through any arguments that were
  // passed into myJson(), and then set the headers you want
  return d3.json.apply(null, arguments)
    .header('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
}
```

thereby allowing you to make json requests like this

```
myJson('/path', function(json) {...})
```

This of course requires you to use `myJson()` in place of `d3.json` everywhere. However, if you're sure that you always, always, always want to set those headers by default whenever you call `d3.json`, then you can go ahead and (gasp) overwrite `d3.json` with something like the custom `myJson` above. For example:

```
// save the originial implementation of d3.json
var d3Json = d3.json;

// define your own implementation of d3.json, which relies on
// the original implementation
d3.json = function() {
  // notice the use of d3Json — NOT d3.json, as shown above
  return d3Json.apply(null, arguments)
    .header('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
}
```

And from then on, when you call `d3.json(...)` from anywhere in your app (and this includes any vendor code that might call `d3.json`) it will run your custom function, which in turn will call the **original** `d3.json(...)` and set the default headers.

Comment: Thanks, was just wondering if there was a way before I started going through the source code. Will implement the second recommendation as some requests come from a third party. Will mark as answer in a couple of days if there are no other responses.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, `meetamit`'s d3 suggestion didn't work for me, so I've changed it a little bit as [how the d3 documentation suggests to add the header](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests#header):

```
// save the originial implementation of d3.json
var d3Json = d3.json;

// define your own implementation of d3.json, which relies on
// the original implementation
d3.json = function(url, handler) {
    // notice the use of d3Json — NOT d3.json, as shown above
    return d3Json(url).header('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest').get(handler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now in the distant future of 2021, D3 uses the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) rather than XHR. This means that the method of setting headers on a request is different.

The D3 code for the `json()` method is as follows:

```js
function json(input, init) {
  return fetch(input, init).then(responseJson);
}
```

As can be seen, the D3 `json()` method allows passing through a configuration object directly to the Fetch API. This means that if you call the method in the following way you can set the headers on the request.

```js
d3.json("/some-path-to-call", {headers: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}})
```